# Updating a Firefox registry entry

Tags: firefox, registry, ocs

On some of my company's computers, there are two positions of FireFox (old and current version) in Control Panel Uninstall list (only one FF is installed). That makes a mess in our inventory (OCS). I found that it's because of a wrong registry entry in: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Mozilla Firefox (old version of FF here). After deleting it, Uninstall list looks fine, but our inventory can't find any Firefox on that computer now, coz there isn't an entry of a current version. So I figured that it reads the version from that very entry.

Now, is there any way to edit the old reg entry, so it will update to a new version of FF? Or is there any way, to create a proper registry entry automaticaly from a firefox location? There are too many computers, to do it manualy.

Edit: I found out the other wayt to solve this. I just need to change the location from which OCS reads software info. From the reg entry I wrote above, to other - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\folder_with_curret_FF_version. And now I'm stuck, coz I don't know how to do it. :/